# eclipse.ini file not found in eclipse.exe folder in windows 100

Tags: windows-10

My eclipe returned error-13 on opening the application after installation.

I have mined varius sites which directing me to change the configuration in eclipse.ini file.

But I couldn't find hat file in eclipse.exe folder in windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

```
I am using luna.  On my system its located at:  X:\eclipse Luna
My operating system on this computer is, windowsXP Professional
In a non-edited file I presently have:

-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
```

plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m